# What's wrong with pymongo "OperationFailure"

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

the source code is below:

```
# total_record with more than 4 millon datas, which comes from file
n = 200
idlist = [ total_record[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(total_record ), n)]
for sub_list in idlist:
    ret = self.table.find({'_id': {'$in': sub_list}})
    for r in ret:
        # some logic to process r
```

The code can process part of the data correctly, and then encounter the following problems. In addition, this is only read operation, not write operation

```
    for r in ret:
  File "/data/yard/base/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1189, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/data/yard/base/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1126, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(g)
  File "/data/yard/base/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 982, in __send_message
    helpers._check_command_response(first)
  File "/data/yard/base/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: operation was interrupted
```

My python version is 3.6.4, 
and pymongo version is 3.7.1

Comment: Might not be the cause of the issue but `total_record [i:i + n]` has a space in it, it should be `total_record[i:i + n]`

Comment: Thank you for advising.  This misspelling is due to my copy and paste.

Comment: Whenever this exception occurs there should be an [error code also provided](https://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Error/OperationFailure.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no error code with the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can try initializing the MongoDB Cursor with `no_cursor_timeout` and limit batch size with `batch_size()`

```
for sub_list in idlist:
    ret = self.table.find({'_id': {'$in': sub_list}}, no_cursor_timeout=True).batch_size(40)
    try:
        for r in ret:
            # some logic to process r
    finally:
        ret.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i will have a try.